# How RNN extract features from an image

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Hy, I am currently working on my thesis which is to build OCR for Urdu language. I have text, written on images. In CNN I know there are convolutional and pooling layers to learn patterns or (extract features). What I have read about RNN is that it learn sequences. I want to ask how RNN extract features to know,  what is in image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RNN** basically need some features and label at training phase to learn sequence in the data. In case of numerical data there is not any problem, we simply divide our data set into features (X) and a target value (Y). But in case of **Image data**, we use combination of CNN and RNN(**CNN-RNN**). Here on the top of RNN layers (**LSTM or GRU**) Convolution layers are used to extract features from image and then we feed these features to RNN layers.

Answer (score 1):

the RNN network use of hidden layer that update over time. Taking samples and predict next samples based on decreasing Error(or loss). 
the LSTM is a type of RNNs that overcome to forgetting long-time dependencies. Might this type, could be useful for your thesis.